# Perl Hash of Hashes issues

Tags: perl

I am getting very confused with hashes of hashes and cant find a solution.

I have some hashes

```
%myHash = {'e5' => '0', 'f7' => 'b'};
%myHash2 = {'e5' => '1', 'f7' => 'a'};
%newHash;
$newHash{'move0'} = {%myHash};
$newHash{'move1'} = {%myHash2};
print Dumper(\%newHash);
```

OUTPUT:

```
 $newHash = {
          'move0' => {
                       'e5' => '0',
                       'f7' => 'b'
                     }, 
          'move1' => {
                       'e5' => '1',
                       'f7' => 'a'
                     } 
            };
```

Then when I try and get one hash out of my hash of hashes and store it in a hash I cant get it to work.

```
my %hash = {$newHash{"move0"}};
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

OUTPUTS:

```
 $hash = {
           'HASH(0x26b7d40)' => undef
         };
```

I have tried many other ways of getting my hash from the hash of hashes and assigning it to a hash but its not working.

Comment: You should use `strict` and `warnings` pragma. Then you would get a clue from the compiler what is going on here. Curly braces generates a hash reference. You probably meant to use parenthesis (instead of curlies) like: `my %myHash = ('e5' => '0', 'f7' => 'b')` ? This generates a regular hash (not a reference to a hash).

Comment: Always put at the top of the program: `use warnings;` and `use strict;`.There are  basic syntax errors here and you would know about them with these pragmas in effect.  You should be getting warnings without them as well, don't you?

Comment: This is a snipping of my code, I am using strict warnings etc in my main program.

Comment: They thought you did use `use warnings;` because your code issues warnings. But that's not actually the issue at all. The real issue is that you lied about the code that you ran. Please fix your question so that the code in it actually produces the output in it.

Comment: This won't run with `use strict;`.  You cannot assign a scalar `{..}` to a hash `%h`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make a copy of a hash, one uses

```
my %dst = %src;
```

You have a reference to the hash, so that would be

```
my %dst = %{ $newHash{move0} };
```

---

But what's with all the wasteful copies??? Use

```
my %move0 = ( e5 => '0', f7 => 'b' );
my %move1 = ( e5 => '1', f7 => 'a' );
my %data = (
   move0 => \%move0,
   move1 => \%move1,
);
```

or

```
my %data = (
   move0 => { e5 => '0', f7 => 'b' },
   move1 => { e5 => '1', f7 => 'a' },
);
```

then

```
my $move = $data{move0};
```